# delete the next last div of a div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="divwarp">
    <div id="divRow0">
        <div id="divRow00"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="divRow1">
        <div id="divRow10"></div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

I want to delete the last div with ID divRow1.
I tried `$('#divRules').find('div:last').remove();` but it delete div with ID divRow10.

Comment: $('#divRules').children('div:last').remove(); this works :)

Comment: Post it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me. $('#divRules').children('div:last').remove();